# Why does fadein and fadeout not animate unless I resize the window?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I'm trying to achieve a slideshow effect, but the image does not seem to redraw, does this has something to do with how I'm looping this function?

here is the snippet:

```
function changePic() {
            if (n == pics.length) {
                pics = shuffleArray(pics);
                n = 0;
            }
            var pic = "media/" + pics[n];
            n++;
            $("#dinner").fadeOut("slow",function(){
                $("#dinner").attr("src",pic).load(function(){
                    $("#dinner").fadeIn("slow",function(){
                        setTimeout(changePic,slideDuration);
                    });
                });
            });
}
```

here's the  [live site](http://ukdinner.com)

Comment: tried wrapping it in `$(document).ready( //code here );` ?

Comment: if `$(document).ready();` doesn't work, try this: `$(window).load(function() {changePic()});`

Comment: @Azrael @djzorrow If you look at the live site, this `changePic` function is only called from `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: This works on Firefox - but on Chrome your pictures (except for the first one - are not properly sized - they do get loaded - you can see a little square. Try setting some width/height

Comment: same issue when wrapped in `.ready()`. I seem to have pinpointed the issue - when I remove the CSS animation from the title text, the fades seem to work; does anyone know why these would clash?

Comment: Your code works OK stand-alone... Update this JSFiddle with the styling to play with it: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/5dqsaafs/1/